# show empty message on empty taxonomy wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, is-empty

im working on wordpress theme and everything goes fine but i have this problem

i make a php page "taxonomy.php" it shows custom taxonomy posts

the problem i have if i visit empty taxonomy it shows me a posts from other taxonomy insted of showing error message

the code i use to display:

```
<?php 
get_header();  
$temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('showposts=9&post_type=covers'.'&paged='.$paged); 
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;

?> 

<div id="primary" class="site-content span12">
  <div id="content" class="entry-content" role="main">
        <?php
$product_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'cover_category');
if(!empty($product_terms)){
  if(!is_wp_error( $product_terms )){
    foreach($product_terms as $term){

      echo '<h4 style="color:#cb2027">'.$term->name.'</h4>'; 

      //Category Desciprion
      echo '<h6 style="color:#cb2027">'.term_description($term->term_id, 'cover_category').'</h6>'; 
    }
  }
}


?>


<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now if i visit this 
`http://localhost/wp/?cover_category=as` -> this taxonomy **as** have 6 posts and show them correct

if i visit this `http://localhost/wp/?cover_category=wawa` -> this taxonomy **wawa** have 0 posts and it show posts from **as** taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for default category page:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div style="height: 190px;">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                       <div class="thumb" style="float: left; width:170px;">
                           <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                       </div>    
                     <?php endif; ?>
                   <div style="float:left; width:475px;">   
                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button-primary">En savoir plus</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h3>Page en cours de construction</h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: im using custom taxonomy wanna bring posts out of it

Comment: You can change the name of your file taxonomy.php to taxonomy-{name}.php . that will work :)